# Can't check checkbox if high score is greater than 20

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_achievements);
    CheckBox twentyCheck = findViewById(R.id.twentyCheck);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("GAME DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int highScore = settings.getInt("HIGH_SCORE", 0);
    if (highScore >= 20) {
        twentyCheck.isChecked();
    }
}
```

See full code here: [High Score](http://tpcg.io/jTm7cE)

I need help on how to check the checkbox if the high score is greater than 20.

Comment: Also, `isChecked` returns the current state of the checkbox, it doesn't set it. Pretty sure you're looking for `setChecked`, but I don't remember if that's the exact naming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling isChecked, which returns true or false depending on if the Checkbox is checked. You should instead call setChecked.

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_achievements);
     CheckBox twentyCheck = findViewById(R.id.twentyCheck);
     SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("GAME DATA", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
     int highScore = settings.getInt("HIGH_SCORE", 0);
     if (highScore >= 20) {
         twentyCheck.setChecked(true);
     }
 }
```